# Where to find jobs execution logs for Apache Tez

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-tez

I have set up tez over hadoop. I am running query `select COUNT(DISTINCT first_name) from user_test where country='India';`using hive.

When I use `hive.execution.engine=mr` (mr) as execution environment, Job executes successfully and also logs can be seen on Hadoop UI. But when running same job with `tez` I am getting below error and also i am not able to find logs.

`Launching Job 1 out of 1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask`

I am not able to find the detailed logs for the error, any help where are logs file getting generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for an applicationId in the hive console log. Logs can then be obtained by:

> $bin/yarn logs -applicationId  > app_logs.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HDP (Hortonworks distribution), then there is Tez view which provides you navigate through Tez logs using browser.